# actual meaning of average - and implying it to functions

Tags: integration, area, average

The very basic idea of average is:

$$ average=\frac{{x_1} + {x_2}....{x_n}}{n}\ $$

A function is nothing but just a graphical representation of a set of points(in the cartesian plane in this instance):
[image]

now on the interval [a, b], the the average of the function should had been

$$average = \frac{{y_1} + {y_2}......{y_n}}{N}$$, where n is supposed to be the number of y in the interval. Instead, y<sub>av</sub> is treated as the area divided by it's interval b-a.

Now, the average's definition could also say, finding one such value which could approximate to a certain range it's entire values of concern:

[image]

Again, interpreting a function's average as an area would give us the value of on square of a unit which would be a centrally approximated value of it's entire area; but, what I'm confused at is that y1, y2, etc.. are offset from the x axis and not functions themselves representing the entire range of points. So, how would the definition of average and the interpretation of area towards the average of a function make sense?

Comment: An Average is not consistent with an area - It is consistent with a point in the given domain. i.e. an average of y-values give you a level with respect to y. An average in a N-d space gives you the average centroid in that given space. Not an area, but a point. In any case I will default to someone more apt in this area of analysis.

Answer (score 1):

For a function $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, the average of the function on an interval $[a,b]$ is given by

$$\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f(x)\,dx = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n f\left(a + i\cdot\frac{b-a}{n}\right) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{y_1 + y_2 + \cdots + y_n}{n}$$

where the $y_i$ are the function values at points in the interval $[a,b]$ given by
$y_i = f\left(a + i\cdot\frac{b-a}{n}\right)$.

The integral is the area under the curve and we divide by $b-a$, which is the length of the interval.

Comment: HOW is it the area by it's interval?

Comment: @BeshalJaenal By the definition of the Reimann integral. See my edit.

Comment: Going still to a deeper aspect, area are just units of square right?, if we divide the area by the interval then we get an _average_ value of the square, right? How is this a value that's associated more with the area _below_ the curve, giving us _the average of the curve_?

Comment: wait your second edit loaded in a bit later

Comment: @BeshalJaenal The average of the function is the average height above the axis. I'm not sure what you mean by the "average value of the square".

Comment: @BeshalJaenal Yes. This is how the integral is defined. As a [limit](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/28/Riemann_integral_regular.gif).

Comment: the second proof you did above was what I needed, is this also the reimann integral you mentioned above? I want to have a look at a more detailed version of it. "limit x->inf. y1 .....yn/n, where can I get a detailed proof of this?

Answer (score 0):

Imagine we want to find the are under a graph called $f$. If we know that the average of $f(x)$ starting from $x = a$ to $x = b$ is equal to $n$, we can say that the area under the curve is:

$n * (b-a)$

So in order to calculate n, we can do this:

$\int_{a}^{b}{f(x).dx} = n * (b-a) => n = \frac{\int_{a}^{b}{f(x).dx}}{b - a}$

Which is the same as "the area under the curve / $\Delta{x}$".